At what stage of the species distribution modelling to standardize variables and check for collinearity
I try to model the distribution (ecological niche) of a species using a generalized linear model (glm() in R) based on several climatic variables and then apply the model to predict (map) the distribution in my territory of interest. The variables are available for my territory as raster files.
My procedure is as follows: first standardize the variables using the mean and standard deviation from the entire target territory, preparing rasters of the standardized variables; then extract the standardized variables for my presence/absence locations and use it for modelling.
Is this order the right one or I should instead first extract the original variavles for the presence/absence locations and then standardize that sample based on its mean and standard deviation? If this second approach is better, how to prepare the rasters for prediction (mapping) – should I standardize them using the means and the standard deviations of the sample? This last question is discussed here, but it seems there are no definite conclusion.
Similarly, at what level to check for collinearity of variables – the full dataset (territory) or the sample?
EDIT:
To give more context on the species distribution modeling:
I have a record (of geographic locations) of presences and absences of a species within my study area but I want to know what is the probability of the species to be present in any part of the territory including places with no direct observations. The territory is represented as a raster (grid of cells) so I am interested of the probability of occurrence in all the cells. With the species distribution model (SDM) I want to predict the probability of a species occurring knowing the environment conditions at that place (grid cell) and having a model of the relationship of the species with these environment variables. The model was logistic regression and the training data came from the same territory so it is like an interpolation.
More generally:
The aim of my regression analysis is to make prediction. Right from the beginning I have the independent variables for all cases (i.e. grid cells, in my context) I want to predict. For part of the cases I have the dependent variable so I can build the model with that sample. If we assume the modelling method require standardization of the independent variables “what” should I standardize, the entire dataset (the entire raster, in my case) or the sample used to build the model? In other words, the data in the sample can be standardized using two different sets of Mean and StdDev, these of the sample itself and these of the entire dataset.

If you pose the questions in a very general manner, maybe it would be easier to help. We don't have enough context this way.

It appears you are trying to model a distribution of animals across a space. In this case, I don't think you even want a generalized linear model. You have to account for the spatial nature of the data. This will violate the assumption of independent errors.

Ordinarily standardization is used to reduce numerical errors in limited-precision floating point calculations; and often that is automatically done by software.  Maybe you shouldn't be worrying about this--there are other far more important issues to deal with, such as considering what an appropriate model might be and how to choose a good estimator or predictor.

I don't know why you want to standardize the variables for predictive models.

@stweb I thought standardization is necessary for some methods and that it will help in assessing predictor importance.
